# How to read XML text (not attributes) into float?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Hey guys I am trying to read 3D points (X, Y, Z) (all Float) from an XML file in C#.

The XML for each point used to be formatted like this:

```
<Point X="-4865.764" Y="-4945.29" Z="261.1602"/>
```

and I could read this with the following:

```
return new XElement("Point", new XAttribute("X", X), new XAttribute("Y", Y), new XAttribute("Z", Z));
```

But now I have to read my points from XML formatted like this:

```
<Point>679.7905 -4312.875 60.93259</Point>
```

How can I read the XML into my float variables (X, Y and Z) when it is formatted as shown above?

Thanks alot,

Jesse

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to split the value, e.g.

```
string[] values = element.Value.Split(' ');
// Possibly do validation here to check there are 3 values?
// Note the specification of the culture here - otherwise if you're in a culture
// which uses "," as the decimal separator, it won't do what you want...
float x = float.Parse(values[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
float y = float.Parse(values[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
float z = float.Parse(values[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```